# What -t switch do in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

In scrapy tutorials said that for saving output to csv or any other format we should use this command:

```
scrapy crawl spider -o result.csv -t csv
```

in general we can use this command:

```
scrapy crawl my_spider -o file_name.extension -t extension
```

but I used this command without -t and there is no problem:

```
scrapy crawl spider -o result.csv
```

My question is what is role of `-t`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are not sure, [look into the source code](http://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/).

According to the [`crawl.py` source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/342cb622f1ea93268477da557099010bbd72529a/scrapy/commands/crawl.py), if you don't specify the format explicitly, Scrapy would detect it - the extension of the file name would be used as a format:

```
if not opts.output_format:
    opts.output_format = os.path.splitext(opts.output)[1].replace(".", "")
```

In your case `csv` would be used.

Comment: it means I can save to csv with this code: scrapy crawl spider -o r -t csv. is this correct?

Comment: @SaraSantana yes, you should be able to do so - try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can generally get an explanation of command line tool options by calling the command with the `--help` option:

```
C:\>scrapy crawl --help

Usage
=====
  scrapy crawl [options] <spider>

Run a spider

Options
=======
--help, -h              show this help message and exit
-a NAME=VALUE           set spider argument (may be repeated)
--output=FILE, -o FILE  dump scraped items into FILE (use - for stdout)
--output-format=FORMAT, -t FORMAT
                        format to use for dumping items with -o
...
```

so `-t` is used to specify the format used when dumping items to a file.